# How to replace only single numbers with another number in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
   date
0   1
1   2
2   23
3   31
4   4
...
n    3
```

How can I **only** replace all the numbers from 1 to 9 (e.g. **numbers with one digit**) with the following format:

```
01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09
```

I tried to do with pandas replace function the following:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].replace(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']),
                                                          [' 01 ', ' 02 ', ' 03 ', '04 ', ' 05 ', ' 06 ', ' 07 ', ' 08 ', ' 09 '],regex=True)
```

However, it didn't worked because it is modifying **all** (i.e. numbers with more than one digit) the numbers inside the dataframe. Thus, how can I normalize the date column?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If needed cast the column to `str` using `astype(str)`, then call [`str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html#pandas.Series.str.zfill) to 0 pad those numbers:

```
In [13]:
df['date'] = df['date'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
df

Out[13]:
  date
0   01
1   02
2   23
3   31
4   04
```

regarding your comment:

```
In [17]:
df['year'] = '20' + df['date']
df

Out[17]:
  date  year
0   01  2001
1   02  2002
2   23  2023
3   31  2031
4   04  2004
```

the above works when the column dtype is already `str`

Comment: Thanks, I did not know this was possible to do... this solution is fine. However, what about if I have the same issue for years?. For example consider a column years with 23, 12, 15, etc. Then I need to impute 20 at the left side of the digit... How can I do that?.

Comment: If already a str then you can just do `'20' + df['year']` or `'20' + df['year'].astype(str)`

Comment: Could you provide the example?... Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well I forgot to mention that all some instances of the pandas dataframe have the right format of the year (e.g. 2011), when I apply the string concatenation I mess instances like 2011 by reformating into 202011. How can I apply it into instances that only have two digits? @edchum

Comment: sorry was busy with family stuff, to answer your question I think `df['year'] = np.where(df['date'].str.len() == 4, '20' + df['date'])` should work

Answer (score 1):

Try `^([0-9])$` for the pattern and `0\1` for the replacement:

```
>>> df = p.DataFrame(data={'date': ['1', '2', '12', '31']})
>>> df['date'].replace('^([0-9])$', r'0\1', regex=True)

0    01
1    02
2    12
3    31
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Reading the comments that you wrote on other questions, it seems like you are doing date formatting. I believe it's better to use [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) for this. Here's an example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> df = p.DataFrame(data={'date': ['1', '2', '12', '31'], 'month': ['1', '2', '5', '12'], 'year': ['07', '10', '16', '17']})
>>> dates = df.apply(lambda row: datetime(year=2000+int(row['year']), month=int(row['month']), day=int(row['date'])), axis=1)
>>> dates

0   2007-01-01
1   2010-02-02
2   2016-05-12
3   2017-12-31
dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> dates.apply(lambda row: row.strftime('%x'))

0    01/01/07
1    02/02/10
2    05/12/16
3    12/31/17
dtype: object
>>> dates.apply(lambda row: row.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

0    2007-01-01
1    2010-02-02
2    2016-05-12
3    2017-12-31
dtype: object
```

This way, you get better control over the date format.

**Edit**

If you need even more control over the conversion, make a function instead:

```
>>> def convert_dates(row):
...     year = row['year']
...     month = row['month']
...     day = row['date']
...     if '' in [year, month, day]:
...         return None # Don't bother with empty values 
...     year, month, day = [int(x) for x in [year, month, day]]
...     if year < 100:
...         year += 2000
...     return datetime(year, month, day)
... 
>>> df = p.DataFrame(data={'date': ['11', '2', '1', '31'], 'month': ['08', '2', '5', '12'], 'year': ['1985', '10', '16', '']})
>>> df.apply(convert_dates, axis=1)

0   1985-08-11
1   2010-02-02
2   2016-05-01
3          NaT
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: in a pandas dataframe?.

Comment: Yes, like your code, but with a different pattern. I added an example.

Comment: I updated this answer with how to use `apply` to create an actual `datetime` object instead, for easier formatting.

Comment: I got `ValueError: ("invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''", 'occurred at index 0')`. Some rows are empty.

Comment: Well I forgot to mention that all some instances of the pandas dataframe have the right format of the year (e.g. 2011), when I apply the string concatenation I mess instances like 2011 by reformating into 202011. How can I apply it into instances that only have two digits?

Comment: Sounds like your data is a bit messy. I'd try to maybe fix the data at the source rather than in pandas. You could write a more complex function and use `apply` with that function instead.

Comment: I would do the same... the thing is that is just a text blob I can't fix it

Comment: For this case the regex was an option I tried: `df['years'].replace('^([0-9])$', r'20\2', regex=True)`. Nevertheless is not making any effect on instances where I just have: 11, 12, 13

Comment: Regexes could probably work, but end up being overly complex. See my update in this answer.

Comment: I tried this then: `df['years'].replace('^([\d\d])$', r'20\2', regex=True)
` and still the same?... probably for this case just a regex works..

Answer (score 1):

Use word boundaries:

Find: `\b(\d)\b`
Replace: `0$1`

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex, something like

```
p = re.compile(r'\b\d\b')
p.sub(lambda x: '0'+x.group(), '0 1 2 23 34 5')
## result: '00 01 02 23 34 05'
```