# How to concatenate some digits to another digit given the following constraints?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

I am normalizing some year values inside a pandas dataframe.

```
   years

0  2011
1  2012
2  2050
3  11
4  23
5  01
 ....
n  2015
```

As you can see there are values that are wrong, since they must be 4 digits. Thus, I would like to transform them into four digits numbers:

```
   year

0  2011
1  2012
2  2050
3  2011
4  2023
5  2001
  ...
n  2015
```

For the above, in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42350185/how-to-replace-only-single-numbers-with-another-number-in-a-pandas-dataframe/42350252?noredirect=1#comment71854122_42350252) I learned that you can use function replace for this task:

```
df['years'].replace('\b\d{2}\b.*?', r'20\2', regex=True)
```

I tried with a different regex:

```
^[0-9]{2}
^[0-9]{2}.*
(\d\d)*
^(\d{2})
r'\b\d{2}\b'
```

However, these are not working. Therefore, how can I normalize with four digits (adding `20`) the above dataframe?

Comment: What is the dtype of `years` column?

Comment: @MaxU  `year         object dtype: object`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df.years = pd.to_numeric(df.years, errors='coerce')

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   years
0   2011
1   2012
2   2050
3     11
4     23
5      1
6   2015

In [13]: df.loc[df.years <= 50, 'years'] += 2000

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
   years
0   2011
1   2012
2   2050
3   2011
4   2023
5   2001
6   2015
```

**UPDATE:** converting to string:

```
In [35]: df
Out[35]:
    years
0  2011.0
1  2012.0
2  2050.0
3  2011.0
4  2023.0
5  2001.0
6     NaN
7  2015.0

In [36]: df.dtypes
Out[36]:
years    float64
dtype: object

In [37]: df.years.where(df.years.notnull(), '')
Out[37]:
0    2011
1    2012
2    2050
3    2011
4    2023
5    2001
6
7    2015
Name: years, dtype: object
```

Comment: My numbers turned into floats: `2019.0`

Comment: This is the most direct, nice!

Comment: @tumbleweed, that means you have some values that can't be converted to numbers, for example strings (like `'aaa'`) or `NaN`'s or dates, etc.

Comment: What about converting them into strings?.

Comment: @tumbleweed, what is your end-goal?

Comment: I will concatenate them with another column to get the desired format

Comment: df.loc[df.years <= 50, 'years'] is excellent, I was trying to play with conventional if.

Comment: I tried to: `df['years'].apply(str)` and still the same

Comment: @tumbleweed, please see UPDATE section

Comment: Thanks you very much, this solution was neat.

Comment: @tumbleweed, glad i could help :)

Comment: However, when I do: `df.tocsv()` the years are floats insted of strings... why this is happening?

Comment: @tumbleweed, let me try to reproduce it

Comment: The thing is that I am recovering this data from a textblob

Comment: And the problem comes wen I want to do: `df[['year','month', 'date']].apply(lambda x : '{}{}'.format(x[0],x[1],x[2]), axis=1)` (year month day)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136187/discussion-between-maxu-and-tumbleweed).

Answer (score 1):

```
df['years'].astype(int).apply(lambda year: 2000 + year if year < 2000 else year).astype(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

If years is not already a string, you can convert it:

```
df['years'] = df['years'].astype(str)
```

Now you can find the entries that have "short year" values, i.e., where years is less than four characters.  Save it into a Series of bool to index into the dataframe:

```
short_years = df['years'].str.len() < 4
```

Finally modify values to be four-characters long:

```
df.loc[short_years, 'years'] = df[short_years]['years'].map(lambda yr: '2{:03d}'.format(int(yr)))
```

This use of a lambda in map assumes that all of the values in years can be converted to int.  If that is not the case, you might need to define a function:

```
def atoi(s):
    """Convert string to integer, if possible, otherwise return None."""
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return None

df.loc[short_years, 'years'] = df[short_years]['years'].map(atoi)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help tom